# AJAX4JSF/AjaxStateHolder | Session Memory Leak

Tags: java, performance, jsf, memory-leaks, ajax4jsf

I am working on the performance tuning of an enterprise web application with about 300 simultaneous user. I have noticed from the GC log that the application heap is always growing and objects are always accumulating even after Full GC. I've acquired a production heap dump and I was surprised that the session objects are occupying more than 90% of the heap size! That's all because of the AjaxStateHolderObject.

The application is runing on JSF 1.X and RichFaces 3.3.0.

Before starting this discussion I tried the following:

- Added the following code to web.xml

`<context-param>`

`<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>`

`<param-value>1</param-value>`

`</context-param>`

- Added the following code to web.xml

`<context-param>`

`<param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>`

`<param-value>1</param-value>`

`</context-param>`

`<context-param>`

`<param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>`

`<param-value>1</param-value>`

`</context-param>`

- Upgraded from RichFaces 3.3.0 to 3.3.3

All the above attempts failed to solve the memory leakage problem.

**Updates**

*A single user session can consume up to 25 MB because of the AjaxStateHolder huge size.

*Most of the managed beans of the application are request scope and there is no unused referenced objects in session, the only problem concerning memory is the ajaxStateHolder.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Any kind of help will be appreciated because I didn't find anything concerning this issue on the web.

Comment: You really do not give enough specifics for us to help you.  The session may be large but perhaps that is because your application server is serving 3k concurrent users, that is a LOT.  How much memory typically is being consumed by a single user session?  Are objects being stored in session that can actually be stateless?  Can you utilize view scoped for some of your managed beans to limit stateful scope to a single page?  Are their unused objects being referenced in session managed beans that are no longer being read or used?  Simple configuration tweaks might not make a difference here.

Comment: @maple_shaft Sorry its a typo only, I meant 300 users only. :) A single user session can consume up to 25 MB. Most of the managed beans are request scope. There is no unused referenced objects in session, the only problem concerning memory is the ajaxStateHolder.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have run into the JSF/a4j session memory leak defect.  See link below for more description on the matter:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-3878

It appears as if the view state is being cached in session and not cleaned up.  It is a bug with a4j and cannot be fixed, just worked around.  The configurations you added to `web.xml` are the only suggested workaround but apparently this does not help too much.

It seems a4j is not very scalable so perhaps the best long term solution is to slowly refactor the a4j components out of the application and replace them with a different component framework?  Sorry I could not be more of a help and I wish you luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) Can you please guide me on how to refactor/replace the a4j components?

Comment: @M.ES This is too complex and specific to your situation to give you a good answer.  There a number of different component frameworks that can viably replace a4j:  IceFaces, PrettyFaces, Primefaces to name a few, however they might have similar issues with memory management as well.  My advice is to do a prototype and try removing a4j from a single page and replace it with components from another framework.  Place instrumentation code in your prototype and perform a load test.  Monitor the memory usage and compare to a4j.  It would be interesting to know which has the best memory management.

Comment: cont... This is a common problem with JSF it seems and there are not many good blogs on JSF performance tuning that I can find at least.